# Insert with db.SaveChanges() not inserted in table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I intend to insert forms data into a data table but it's not working.

I have used Code first to update data table.

```
public partial class tmp2 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Tmembre",
            c => new
                {
                    Idmembre = c.Int(),
                    Nommembre = c.String(),
                    Prenommembre = c.String(),
                    Mailmembre = c.String(),
                    SRCImage = c.String(),
                    Idassociation = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Idmembre);

    }

}
```

The identity is not the primary key.

In the global model I have :

```
public partial class Tmembre
{
    [Key] 
    public int Idmembre { get; set; }
    public string Nommembre { get; set; }
    public string Prenommembre { get; set; }
    public string Mailmembre { get; set; }
    public string SRCImage { get; set; }
    public int Idassociation { get; set; }
}
```

and to add a membre in the member table I do :

```
        else if (Request["boutonmembre"] == "Ajouter")
        {
            if (myFile != null && myFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //string fileNameApplication = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(NAMEtxtFileName.FileName);
                string fileExtensionApplication = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName);

                // generating a random guid for a new file at server for the uploaded file
                string newFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtensionApplication;
                // getting a valid server path to save
                string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("Content\\themes\\image"), newFile);

                if (myFile.FileName != String.Empty)
                {
                    myFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                }
            }

            bool formok = true;
            Tmembre Membreajoute = new Tmembre();

            Membreajoute.SRCImage = "\\themes\\image\\photo_identite.jpg";

            if (Request["nom"] != "")
            {
                Membreajoute.Nommembre = Request["nom"];
            }
            else
            {
                formok = false;
            }

            if (Request["prenom"] != "")
            {
                Membreajoute.Prenommembre = Request["prenom"];
            }
            else
            {
                formok = false;
            }

            if (Request["mail"] != "")
            {
                Membreajoute.Mailmembre = Request["mail"];
            }
            else
            {
                formok = false;
            }

            if (formok == true)
            {
                //Sur la base du membre numéro 1
                Membreajoute.Idassociation = int.Parse(Request["idassociation"].ToString());
                int membremaxid = db.TmembresansEDMdb.Max(u => u.Idmembre);
                Membreajoute.Idmembre = membremaxid + 1;
                db.TmembresansEDMdb.Add(Membreajoute);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Association = db.dbTassociation.Find(Membreajoute.Idassociation);
                ViewData["Nomassociation"] = Association.Nomassociation;
                ViewData["Idassociation"] = Membreajoute.Idassociation;
                mymodel.lstmembre = (from a in db.TmembresansEDMdb
                                     where a.Idassociation == Membreajoute.Idassociation
                                     select a).ToList();
            }
```

There are no errors but the row is not inserted in table.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding

```
 Tmembre Membreajoute = new Tmembre();
```

to the database context?

Like:

```
db.Membreajoutes.Add(Membreajoute);
```

Comment: Now I add Membreajoute with add method but the occurs is not inserted.

Answer (score 0):

As per code, few things need to verify step by steps

1. is this created object added in context before saving dbcontext.
   like db.>.Add(Membreajoute). in your case may be db.TmembresansEDMdb.Add(Membreajoute)
2. if you have any existing record, are you able to modify that.
3. Are you able to verify your db config

   Hope this help.

Comment: tks for yours helps. Now I have added the code line you purpose like .add(membreajoute) and I have now an error on the line after : db.savechanges()

Comment: The error is strange : `code`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Idmembre', table 'C:\USERS\DAVID.FERNANDES\DOCUMENTS\DBRESERVATIONSKILLS.MDF.dbo.Tmembre'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated. `code` And when I verify in debug mode `code` Membreajoute.Idmembre = membremaxid + 1; `code` Value of Idmembre is 2. I just have 1 record in datatable with id = 1

Comment: And as you can see The Code for migration don't allow identity (auto increment) but I don't know if there is anything related with the no save changes in datatable

Comment: this is not a strange...its related to your key mapping. can you try this on your key
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] or you can map in your modelbuilder.